# Bash - how to make explicit operator precedence without creating a subshell

Tags: bash, shell, subshell

I'm sure this is posted somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it.

In Bash, how does one specify operator precedence (aka command grouping) without creating a subshell?  In most other languages the`()` do this, but in Bash this runs the commands in a subshell which "discards" environment changes.  I want to specify operator precedence without losing environment changes.

Specifically, I'd like to do something like this and have the entire script exit, not just the subshell in the `()`:

```
die ()
{
    echo "[DIE]: $1"
    exit 1
}

# When installChruby returns an error, print the error message and exit
[[ $CHRUBY =~ [Yy] ]] && (installChruby || die "Error installing chruby")
```

I figured out a "workaround" by doing this, but it's not a pretty one-liner like I want:

```
if [[ $CHRUBY =~ [Yy] ]]; then installChruby || die "Error installing Chruby"; fi
```

The desired outcome is to do nothing and continue if `CHRUBY` is unset, to call the function `installChruby` if `CHRUBY` is either `Y` or `y`, and to call the `die` function only if the `installChruby` function returns false.

Is there an operator in Bash that does this besides `()`, or is there a way to tell the code inside the `()` to not run in a sub-shell?

Comment: Use command grouping `{}`.

Comment: If your goal is `When installChruby returns an error, print the error message and exit`, so using `[[ $CHRUBY =~ [Yy] ]] && installChruby || die "Error installing chruby"` will work as you expected.

Comment: @Gnouc yes, but it also exits when `CHRUBY` is set to something else (like N or n), which is not what is wanted.

Comment: More generally, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270440/simple-logical-operators-in-bash/6270803#6270803

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/247187/135943

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from `man bash`:

```
   { list; }
          list  is  simply executed in the current shell environment.  list must be terminated with a newline or semicolon.
          This is known as a group command.  The return status is the exit status of list.  Note that unlike the  metachar‐
          acters  (  and  ), { and } are reserved words and must occur where a reserved word is permitted to be recognized.
          Since they do not cause a word break, they must be separated from list by whitespace or another shell metacharac‐
          ter.
```

Comment: @Gnouc I think that is because the exit status of `echo 123` is true, thus short-circuit avoids echoing qqwe

Comment: @Freedom_Ben: Misunderstood your question, now I've got it.

Comment: @Gnouc  No worries, thanks for speaking up!  I think it's really helpful to get other perspectives.  I often learn more from other people's questions and comments than I do from the answers, simply because other people think differently.  Also, it helps me to know that I should reword the question to be more explicit. Thanks!

Comment: It would really help to show an example, ideally by modifying the question's script.