# bash if not multiple conditions without subshell?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to combine multiple conditions in a shell if statement, and negate the combination.  I have the following working code for a simple combination of conditions:

```
if [ -f file1 ] && [ -f file2 ] && [ -f file3 ] ; then
  # do stuff with the files
fi
```

This works fine.  If I want to negate it, I can use the following working code:

```
if ! ( [ -f file1 ] && [ -f file2 ] && [ -f file3 ] ) ; then
  echo "Error: You done goofed."
  exit 1
fi
# do stuff with the files
```

This also works as expected.  However, it occurs to me that I don't know what the parentheses are actually doing there.  I *want* to use them just for grouping, but is it actually spawning a subshell?  (How can I tell?)  If so, is there a way to group the conditions without spawning a subshell?

Comment: I suppose I could also use boolean logic to determine the equivalent expression: `if ! [ -f file1 ] || ! [ -f file 2 ] || ! [ -f file3 ] ; then` but I'd like a more general answer.

Comment: You can also negate inside the braces, e. g. `if [[ ! -f file1 ]] && [[ ! -f file2 ]]; then`

Comment: @DopeGhoti, does that work with single brackets?  i.e. is that a bashism only or a POSIX portable syntax?

Comment: Yes, I just tested `if [ ! 1 -eq 2 ] && [ ! 2 -eq 3 ]; then echo yep; fi` and it works.  I just always write tests with double-braces as a matter of habit.  Also, to ensure it's not `bash`, I further tested `if /bin/test ! 1 -eq 2 && /bin/test ! 2 -eq 3 ; then echo yep; fi` and it works that way also.

Comment: @mikeserv: Neither, the conditions are made up for the purpose of illustration and for simplicity.  My actual use case is for readable files, more like `if [ ! -d mydir ] || [ ! -r mydir/file1 ] || [ ! -r mydir/file2 ] ; then` although now I look at it, (1) the `-d` check is unnecessary given the following two checks and (2) if `file1` and/or `file2` were readable dirs instead of readable files, my script would incorrectly validate them.  That's a corner case though.

Comment: @Wildcard - `[ ! -e file/. ] && [ -r file ]` will drop directories. negate it as you like. of course, that's what `-d` does.

Comment: Related question (similar but not as much discussion and answers not so helpful): http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156885/135943

Comment: Dupe! Cross-site dupe!  Oh no! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916559/test-multiple-file-conditions-in-one-swoop-bash

Comment: Not a duplicate at all.  The subject of this question isn't even touched upon over there.

Comment: @alexgray there's no such thing as a cross-site duplicate. Duplicates only refer to _this_ site. We don't want the same question posted by the same person on different sites of the SE network but similar questions by different people are fine. In any case, that is not a dupe. That one is just asking how to combine conditionals, here the question is about negating a bunch of already combined conditionals without spawning a subshell.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to use `{ list;}` instead of `(list)`:

```
if ! { [ -f file1 ] && [ -f file2 ] && [ -f file3 ]; }; then
  : do something
fi
```

Both of them are [Grouping Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_01), but `{ list;}` executes commands in current shell environment.

Note that, the `;` in `{ list;}` is needed to delimit the list from `}` reverse word, you can use other delimiter as well. The space (or other delimiter) after `{` is also required.

Comment: Thank you!  Something that tripped me up at first (since I use curly braces in `awk` more often than in `bash`) is the need for whitespace after the open curly brace.  You mention "you can use other delimiter as well"; any examples?

Comment: @Wildcard: Yes, the whitespace after the open curly brace is needed. An example for other delimiter is a newline, as you often do want you defining a function.

Comment: @don_crissti: In `zsh`, you can use whitespace

Comment: @don_crissti: the `&` is also a separator, you can use `{ echo 1;:&}`, multiple newline can be use as well.

Comment: You can use any metacharacter quote from manual `they must be separated from list by whitespace or another shell metacharacter.` In bash they are:  `metacharacter:    |  & ; ( ) < > space tab `. For this specific task, I believe that  any of `& ; ) space tab` will work. .... .... From zsh (as a comment): `each sublist is terminated by `;', `&', `&|', `&!', or a newline.`

Comment: @BinaryZebra: Yes, of course. Each shell have their extension. What I said is refer to POSIX standard, which only have `;`, `&` newline and list of newline as separators.

Comment: @cuonglm I am not disagreeing with you. You are right. Just expanding on some details. :-)

Comment: More on the topic, this also mentions that `{}` can be used instead of `()` to avoid the extra subshell: https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-brackets.html

Answer (score 9):

To **portably** negate a complex conditional in shell, you must either apply [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and push the negation all the way down inside the `[` calls...

```
if [ ! -f file1 ] || [ ! -f file2 ] || [ ! -f file3 ]
then
    # do stuff
fi
```

... or you must use `then :; else` ...

```
if [ -f file1 ] && [ -f file2 ] && [ -f file3 ]
then :
else
  # do stuff
fi
```

`if ! command` is not portably available and neither is `[[`.

If you don't need total portability, *don't write a shell script*.  You're actually *more* likely to find `/usr/bin/perl` on a randomly selected Unix than you are `bash`.

Comment: `!` is POSIX which nowadays is portable-enough. Even systems that still ship with the Bourne shell also have a POSIX sh somewhere else on the filesystem which you can use to interpret your standard syntax.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas This is technically true but in my experience it is easier to rewrite a script in Perl than it is to deal with the hassle of locating and activating the POSIX-compliant shell environment starting from `/bin/sh`.  Autoconf scripts do as you suggest, but I think we all know how little of an endorsement that is.

Answer (score 7):

You could use entirely the `test` functionality to achieve what you want. From the man page of `test`:

```
 ! expression  True if expression is false.
 expression1 -a expression2
               True if both expression1 and expression2 are true.
 expression1 -o expression2
               True if either expression1 or expression2 are true.
 (expression)  True if expression is true.
```

So your condition could look like:

```
if [ -f file1 -a -f file2 -a -f file3 ] ; then
    # do stuff with the files
fi
```

For negating use escaped parentheses:

```
if [ ! \( -f file1 -a -f file2 -a -f file3 \) ] ; then
    echo "Error: You done goofed."
    exit 1
fi
# do stuff with the files
```

Comment: Be aware: According to [this document](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16), `-a`, `-o`, and `(`/`)` have been marked obsolescent and should be avoided.

Comment: Avoid `-a`/`-o` binary test operators like the plague, they make for unreliable test expressions and are deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

others have noted the `{` compound command `;}` grouping, but if you are performing identical tests on a *set* you might like to use a different kind:

```
if  ! for f in file1 file2 file3
      do  [ -f "$f" ] || ! break
      done
then  : do stuff
fi
```

...as is elsewhere demonstrated with `{ :;}`, there is no difficulty involved with nesting compound commands...

Note that the above *(typically)* tests for *regular* files. If you're looking only for *existing*, *readable* files which are not directories:

```
if  ! for f in file1 file2 file3
      do  [ ! -d "$f" ] && 
          [   -r "$f" ] || ! break
      done
then  : do stuff
fi
```

If you don't care whether they are directories or not:

```
if  ! command <file1 <file2 <file3
then  : do stuff
fi
```

...works for any *readable*, *accessible* file, but will likely hang for fifos w/out writers.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full-on answer to your main question, but I noticed that
you mention compound testing (readable file) in a comment; e.g.,

```
if [ -f file1 ] && [ -r file1 ] && [ -f file2 ] && [ -r file2 ] && [ -f file3 ] && [ -r file3 ]
```

You can consolidate this a little by defining a shell function; e.g.,

```
readable_file()
{
    [ -f "$1" ]  &&  [ -r "$1" ]
}
```

Add error handling to (e.g., `[ $# = 1 ]`) to taste. 
The first `if` statement, above, can now be condensed to

```
if readable_file file1  &&  readable_file file2  &&  readable_file file3
```

and you can shorten this even further by shortening the name of the function. 
Likewise, you could define `not_readable_file()` (or `nrf` for short)
and include the negation in the function.

Comment: Nice, but why not just add a loop?  `readable_files() {
  [ $# -eq 0 ] && return 1 ;
  for file in "$@" ; do
    [ -f "$file" ] && [ -r "$file" ] || return 1 ;
  done ;
}`  (Disclaimer: I tested this code and it works but it wasn't a one-liner.  I added semicolons for posting here but didn't test their placement.)

Comment: Good point.  I would raise the minor concern that it hides more of the control (conjunction) logic in the function; somebody who reads the script and sees `if readable_files file1 file2 file3` wouldn't *know* whether the function was doing *AND* or *OR* — although (a) I guess it's fairly intuitive, (b) if you're not distributing the script, it's good enough if *you* understand it, and (c) since I suggested abbreviating the function name into obscurity, I'm in no position to talk about readability.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  BTW, the function is fine the way you wrote it, but you can replace `for file in "$@" ; do` with `for file do` — it defaults to `in "$@"`, and (somewhat counter-intuitively) the `;` is not only unnecessary but actually discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Why not this?

```
[[ ! ( -f file1 && -f file2 && -f file3 ) ]]
```

Numerical example:

```
i=1
j=-1
[[ ! ( i -eq 1 && j -eq -1 ) ]]
echo $?
```

Output:

```
1
```

In the other three combinations of `i` and `j`, the output is:

```
0
```

Comment: This is the one of the most appropriate for Bash since 1998. Related: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061 (*Is there a list of which features were added to*...)

Answer (score 1):

You can negate inside the brace tests also, so to reuse your original code:

```
# Using || (or)
if [[ ! -f file1 || ! -f file2 || ! -f file3 ]]; then
    # Do stuff with the files
fi

# Using && (and)
if [[ ! ( -f file1 && -f file2 && -f file3 ) ]]; then
    # Do stuff with the files
fi
```

Comment: You need `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: The test is not "are _any_ of the files not there", the test is "are _none_ of the files there".  Using `||` would execute the predicate if _any_ of the files are not present, not if and only iff _all_ of the files are not present.  NOT( A AND B AND C) is the same as (NOT A) AND (NOT B) AND (NOT C); see the original question.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, cuonglm is right.  It's if not (all files there) so when you split it up this way you need `||` instead of `&&`.  See my first comment below my question itself.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: `not (a and b)` is the same as `(not a) or (not b)`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: It must be Thursday. I never could get the hang of Thursdays.  Corrected, and I will leave my foot-in-mouth for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use them just for grouping, but is it actually spawning a subshell? **(How can I tell?)**

Yes, the commands within the `(...)` are run in a subshell.

To test whether you're in a subshell you can compare the PID of your current shell with the PID of the interactive shell.

```
echo $BASHPID; (echo $BASHPID);
```

Example output, demonstrating that parentheses spawn a subshell and curly braces do not:

```
$ echo $BASHPID; (echo $BASHPID); { echo $BASHPID;}
50827
50843
50827
$
```

Comment: `()` does spawn subshell..perhaps you meant `{}`....

Comment: @heemayl, that's the other part of my question—is there some way I can *see* or *demonstrate* on my screen the fact of a subshell being spawned?  (That could really be a separate question but would be good to know here.)

Comment: @heemayl You're right!  I had done `echo $$ && ( echo $$ )` to compare the PID's and they were the same but just before I submitted the comment telling you you were wrong I tried one other thing.  `echo $BASHPID && ( echo $BASHPID )` gives different PID's

Comment: @heemayl `echo $BASHPID && { echo $BASHPID; }` give the same PID as you suggested would be the case.  Thanks for the education

Comment: @DavidKing, thanks for the test commands using `$BASHPID`, that's the other thing I was missing.

Comment: @DavidKing Since this answer is wrong, consider just deleting it. This way it'll stop distracting the readers, and you'll get back your 4 rep :)

Comment: Or edit it to include the data about the $BASHPID test vs the $$ test.  I would upvote that for sure; no other answer contains the data on how to demonstrate subshells.

Comment: @Ruslan, David King: I've edited the answer to emphasize the *accurate* information which I found so helpful, and to remove the inaccurate points.