# Bash: multiple actions on error response

Tags: bash

I have the following command:

```
/path/to/script.sh && echo "done."; exit 0 || echo "error."; exit 1
```

What I want is to echo "done" and exit with 0 if script succeeds and echo "error" and exit with 1 if it doesn't, but it is not working this way, it misses priorities.

How to handle this?

=== edit. ===

using {} also not works as needed. commands like ./true.sh && { echo done.; ./error.sh; } || { echo err.; echo err1; } works wrong, as it outpust done and all errors after it. ps: true returns 0, error returns 1.

Comment: Possibly related: [Bash - how to make explicit operator precedence without creating a subshell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156885/bash-how-to-make-explicit-operator-precedence-without-creating-a-subshell)

Comment: I stopped reading at `=== edit. ===`, as that doesn't belong in a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if /path/to/script.sh; then
    echo "done."
    exit 0
else
    echo "error."
    exit 1
fi
```

Or, staying with a one-liner:

```
/path/to/script.sh && echo done. || { echo error. ; exit 1; }
```

---

Your edit tells that `A && { B1 ; B2 ; } || { C1 ; C2 ; }` notation doesn't work. assuming B2 returns 1, which isn't your what your initial post states (where's the exit 0? Have you tried adding one?).